# SQL: using join to add columns

Tags: sql, oracle, join

In my database I want to add two views and all columns in one of them to the other.

View one:

```
|Col1 | Col2 |
|     |      |
|     |      |
|     |      |
```

View two:

```
|Col1 | Col3 | Col4| Col5 |
|     |      |     |      |
|     |      |     |      |
|     |      |     |      |
```

My desired result:

```
|Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col4 |
|     |      |      |      |
|     |      |      |      |
|     |      |      |      |
```

I have attempted this with solutions like:

```
SELECT Col1, Col2
FROM view1 NATURAL JOIN(
SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4
FROM view2);
```

Ive also tried with other joins but keep getting error that I'm missing key words.

How do I combine the tables the way I wish?

Comment: Can there be col1 in view1 that don't exists in view2? Can there be col1 in view2 that don't exists in view1?

Comment: All values in Col1 view1 are present in Col1 view2 but there might be values in view2 that are not in view1.

Comment: Then use Codeek's suggestion and outer-join view1 to view2 (`from view1 right join view2`or `from view2 left join view1`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what are your view's schema, but I am assuming col1 from both views match.

```
SELECT v1.Col1, v1.Col2, v2.Col3,v2.col4
FROM View1 v1
INNER JOIN -- OR FULL OUTER JOIN based on your desired result
View v2
on
v1.col1=v2.col1 -- AND/OR any other matching columns. I couldn't find any other one
```